# How to connect to Google Storage with Bucket Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I generated Access & Secret Key put it into Bucket Explorer just as I saw on their screenshots but I get an error that Keys are not recognized on AWS, so it keeps trying to connect to AWS. I have latest version for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Bucket Explorer website](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/google-storage--features-and-benefits-of-bucket-explorer-google-storage.html), it sounds like you need a special version of their software -- however, the download link does not actually seem to have that version available. Have you contact the developers of Bucket Explorer about it?

Alternatively, you can use the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) to upload and access your data in Google Cloud Storage without depending on a particular client application.